# Count character difference between two files in bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix, difference

What would be the best way to count the number of characters that are different between strings in two files. I know how to do this in Python but I need a bash solution.

File contents:

```
ABCDEF
```

```
ABDCEF
```

Output:

```
2
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use `cmp` to compare files with `-l` for verbose, then count the lines with `wc`:

`cmp -bl file1 file2 | wc -l`

http://linux.die.net/man/1/cmp

Comment: I should have been more careful in drafting the question. My files contain variable headers, which I would like to ignore. Is there a cmp equivalent of diff -I '>'?

Answer (score 1):

The following worked,

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Filename: " file1
    awk '(NR>1)' $file1 | tee file1.tmp
        for file in *.txt
            do awk '(NR>1)' $file > $file2.tmp
            cmp -bl file1.tmp $file2.tmp | wc -l
            rm $file2.tmp
        done

function finish {
    rm file1.tmp
}
trap finish EXIT
```